Postgres geography crossing date line, intersecting a polygon
My geography object in postresql DB intersects with date line, but postgres mean what the object don't intersect date line. Actually, the square of the polygon is much smaller. Why it is happens?
The line
select ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(-175 0, 175 0)')

throws across the World. But, I want small line from (-175 0) to (175 0).
How to create object intersecting date line?

Could you explain the actual and detailed behavior you see that make you believe the line throws across the world, and what you have expected? The line logically crosses the antimeridian, as you can check this using e.g. SELECT st_intersects(ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(180 -10, 180 10)'), ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(-175 0, 175 0)')); - this returns true, showing the line intersects the antimeridian.

Thank You, Michael. I have problem with visualization geography objects. Some application can't display any objects intersecting date line (180 meridian). For example pgAdmin 4 Geometry Viewer and some js-libs can't do this.
Now I see only one way to resolve this problem to cat objects by 180 meridian. On MSSQL it looks like this
my_geography.STDifference(geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 90, 180 0)', 4326).STBuffer(10))
.STDifference(geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(180 0, 0 -90)', 4326).STBuffer(10)))

It doesn't run the longer way around the world, it's probably just your viewer only rendering it that way:

You can check its length and intersection with something right between its start point and the 180 meridian:
select 1 as id
, st_length(ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(-175 0, 175 0)'))
, st_length(ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING( 175 0,-175 0)')) as flipped_ends_length
, st_length(st_shortestline( 'point(-175 0)'::geography
                            ,'point( 175 0)'::geography)) as shortest
, st_length('linestring(-175 0,0 0,175 0)'::geography) as the_longer_way_around
, st_intersects(  ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(-175 0, 175 0)')
                , 'polygon((-176 -4,-179 -4,
                            -179  4,-176 4,
                            -176 -4))'::geography);




id
st_length
flipped_ends_length
shortest
the_longer_way_around
st_intersects




1
1113194.907932742
1113194.907932742
1113194.907932742
38961821.777645744
t




The circumference of the globe is about 40075km. The length of of that line is 1113194.9 in meters, so it's around 1113km. One degree of longitude is 111.3km along the equator, so the length of that line is 10 degrees, meaning that it actually runs the shorter way, through the date line. If it ran the other way like the the_longer_way_around line I showed above, it would be 350 degrees long, 38961.8km.
If your line ran the longer way around, it wouldn't intersect the polygon I made right between its start point and the date line, but st_intersects() reports that it does.
Even if you flip the start and end points, PostGIS still assumes it's running the shorter way around.

Demo at db<>fiddle.
